# Accessing variable in another script, The name 'isAnimated' does not exist in the current context

Tags: unity-game-engine, reference, namespaces

I'm trying to access a boolean from another script, which I using a custom namespace. The idea is to have a checkbox in the inspector per item if it should be animated or not. On a weaponmesh, I have a materialoffset animator that should trigger if that box is checked.

```
using MFPSEditor;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using MFPS.Internal.Structures;

namespace MFPS.Addon.Customizer
{
```

At the bottom of this script, I have this:

```
    [System.Serializable]
    public class GlobalCamo
    {
        public string Name;
        [SpritePreview(50)] public Texture2D Preview;
        public MFPSItemUnlockability Unlockability;
        public string Description;
        public bool isAnimated;

        public int Price
        {
            get => Unlockability.Price;
        }

        public bool animatedCamo()
        { 
            return isAnimated;
        }

        public bool isFree() { return Price <= 0; }

        [HideInInspector] public Sprite m_sprite = null;
        public Sprite spritePreview()
        {
            if (m_sprite == null && Preview != null)
            {
                m_sprite = Sprite.Create(Preview, new Rect(0, 0, Preview.width, Preview.height), new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f));
            }
            return m_sprite;
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to access the variable "isAnimated" in the script below:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class MaterialOffsetAnimator : MonoBehaviour
{
    // The material that will be animated
    Material material;

    // The speed at which the offset will be animated
    public Vector2 animationSpeed;

    void Update()
    {
        material = GetComponent<Renderer>().material;

        if ( isAnimated == true )
        {
            // Update the material's offset based on the animation speed
            material.mainTextureOffset += animationSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`isAnimated` is an instance field in your `GlobalCamo` class, not a static field. You can't access it without a reference to an instance of `GlobalCamo`.

You can just make the `isAnimated` field static, like this:

```
public static bool isAnimated;
```

And then access it in `MaterialOffsetAnimator` like this:

```cs
if (GlobalCamo.isAnimated)
{
    // Your code
}
```

---

Also, a side note: You don't need to use `== true` with `booleans`. If a `boolean` is `true`, the condition will evaluate to `true`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I tried what you said, and not I'm getting an error on the condition line:

Assets\Camos\MaterialOffsetAnimator.cs(15,13): error CS0103: The name 'GlobalCamo' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Make sure you're including the namespace the GlobalCamo class exists in. If the GlobalCamo class exists in the MFPS.Addon.Customizer namespace, add "using MFPS.Addon.Customizer;".

Comment: Awesome, that worked! The script itself isn't doing what I wanted it to do but no more errors.

Comment: Actually, I do get an error now on line 16 (the condition): NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
MaterialOffsetAnimator.Update () (at Assets/Camos/MaterialOffsetAnimator.cs:16)

Comment: I realize my mistake; your GlobalCamo class does not inherit from MonoBehaviour. Give me a second, I'll edit my response. You just have to make the isAnimated bool itself static in this case.

Comment: Is there a way to make it without it being static? I can no longer set that variable in the inspector window per item: https://imgur.com/CIQsej0

For reference, this is what I want: https://imgur.com/pdvHDUL

Comment: Without making it static, you would need to somehow get a reference to that specific instance of GlobalCamo, I'm afraid. You could find all instances of that type and filter them, but otherwise, it's very case-specific.